# cause hover only on non-transparent part of png in svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

in my current project, I need to draw dynamically loaded png(so they cannot be prepared...) images inside SVG. And need to add a hover effect on them, which will only work if the non-transparent part of the images has hovered. I found a really old question about it, but it only suggests using a map tag for png, and I cannot prepare them. Another part is in my situation I need to render them inside SVG.
So my question if is this possible, using some SVG functionality, or maybe there is some other way to imitate it with JavaScript?

Right now it renders like this

```
<svg class="svg-img" viewBox="0 0 2901 1639" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
    <image xlink:href="./images/dynamically/loaded.png" x="100" y="500" width="200" height="400">
    </image>
</svg>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could copy the image to canvas and then look at the canvas pixels I guess.

Comment: You could add a transparent polygon to your svg on top of the png with rough the shape of the non transparent part. That's the way I would do it